# load big japanese files in hadoop

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hdfs

i am having on HDFS this huge file which is an extract of my db. e.g.:

```
1||||||1||||||||||||||0002||01||1999-06-01 16:18:38||||2999-12-31 00:00:00||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||2||||0||W.ISHIHARA||||1999-06-01 16:18:38||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||19155||||||||||||||1||1||NBV||||||||||||||U||||||||N||||||||||||||||||||||
1||||||8||2000-08-25 00:00:00||||||||3||||0001||01||1999-06-01 16:26:16||||1999-06-01 17:57:10||||||||||300||||||PH||400||Yes||PH||0255097�`||400||||1||103520||||||1||4||10||||20||||||||||2||||0||S.OSARI||1961-10-05 00:00:00||1999-06-01 16:26:16||�o��������������||�o��������������||1||||����||||1||1994-01-24 00:00:00||2||||||75||1999-08-25 00:00:00||1999-08-25 00:00:00||0||1||||4||||||�l��������������||�o��������������||�l��������������||||�o��������������||NP||||�l��������������||�l��������������||||||5||19055||||||||||1||||8||1||NBV||||||||||||||U||||||||N||||||||||||||||||||||
```

- Size of the file: 40GB
- Number of records: ~120 000 000
- Number of fields: 112
- Field sep: ||
- Line sep: \n
- Encoding: sjis

I want to load this file in hive using pyspark (1.6 with python 3). But my jobs keep failing. 
Here is my code:

```
toProcessFileDF = sc.binaryFiles("MyFile")\
    .flatMap(lambda x: x[1].split(b'\n'))\
    .map(lambda x: x.decode('sjis'))\
    .filter(lambda x: x.count('|')==sepCnt*2)\
    .map(lambda x: x.split('||'))\
    .toDF(schema=tableSchema) #tableSchema is the schema retrieved from hive
toProcessFileDF.write.saveAsTable(tableName, mode='append')
```

I received several errors but amongst other, jave 143 (memory error), heartbeat timeout, and kernel has died. (let me know if you need the exact log errors).

Is it the right way to do it ? Maybe there is a more clever way or more efficient. Can you advice me anything on how to perform this ?

Comment: Did you try to simply create an external hive table over the file? I don't think Spark will be too happy about 40 GB of data in memory  on a small cluster

Comment: 2 problems. Hive in my architecture doesnt have read access on the folder where the file is located. Hive external table doesnt support 2 char field sep. But my cluster is not really a small one.

Comment: Move or copy the HDFS file, then? And I could be wrong but `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '||'` seems like it would work to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the databrick csv reader quite useful to do that.

```
toProcessFileDF_raw = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
                                        .options(header='false',
                                                 inferschema='false',
                                                 charset='shift-jis',
                                                 delimiter='\t')\
                                        .load(toProcessFile)
```

I can use the delimiter option to split with only one character unfortunately. Therefore my solution is to split with tab because i am sure i do not have any in my file. and then I can apply a split on my line.

This is not perfect, but at least i have the right encoding and i do not put everything in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Logs would have been helpful.

`binaryFiles`  will read this as binary file from HDFS as a single record and returned in a key-value pair, where the key is the path of each file, the value is the content of each file.

Note from Spark documentation: Small files are preferred, large file is also allowable, but may cause bad performance.

It would be better if you use `textFile`

```
toProcessFileDF = sc.textFile("MyFile")\
                    .map(lambda line: line.split("||"))\
....
```

Also, one option would be to specify a larger number of partitions when reading in the initial text file (e.g. sc.textFile(path, 200000)) rather than re-partitioning after reading.

Another important thing is to make sure that your input file is splittable (some compression options make it not splittable, and in that case Spark may have to read it on a single machine causing OOMs).

Comment: This is definitely a step in direction but given the question you'll something like `sc.textFile(path, use_unicode=False).map(lambda s: s.decode("sjis"))`

Comment: sc.textFile receive the text in UTF-8 ... therefore, impossible to decode after. Characters unreadable in utf-8 are corrupted.

Comment: @zero323 just for your information, the idea is good but "use_unicode" doesnt work as you think. It brings utf8 decoded file instead of utf8 encoded ... which create error in Japanese char.